# Cassandara server not works on Debian

Tags: java, cassandra, debian

I'm using Debian 9.2.

I'v installed Cassandra 3.11.1 following description in http://cassandra.apache.org/download/.

When I tried to check the nodes without modifying anything in the default configs with `nodetool status` I got the following error:

```
shell:~$ sudo nodetool status
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1877)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:807)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:199)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:167)
```

I checked if the service is running or not, but it's OK (systemctl status cassandra tells it's active).

Another suspicious circumstance: the `/var/lib/cassandra/` folder is totally empty.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the used java version: 1.9.

It is a branch new server, and I installed the current stable java with `sudo apt install oracle-java9-installer` (following [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html) guide).

When later I installed 1.8 with `sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer`, which pulled the `oracle-java8-set-default` and removed automatically the `oracle-java9-set-default`, the Cassandara server started to work fine.

The default java version can be checked with `java -version` in command line.